# code after throw exception in php is not executed

Tags: php, exception

I have a function in PHP that launches an exception, code after that exception is never executed despite the exception where thrown or not.

```
if ($a == 1) throw new Exception("Message");
echo "Dose not execute for $a == 0";
```

I know that when an exception occur code after that won't be reached, but in my example when `$a == 0` no exception is thrown but even `echo` isn't executed.

Well thanks, I hope someone could find out what is going on with my PHP, by the way it is 5.3.

Comment: First thing I would recommend is to always use braces.

Answer (score 6):

Throwing an exception by definition ends the current run (function, method, etc). If you don't want this behavior, don't throw exceptions.

Also, you don't need to echo out the error after the exception was thrown, just include the error with the exception.

Answer (score 2):

IF you're assing '0' to '$a' like this, `$a == 0,` of course it doesn't work, because **you're not assigning a value, but checking for equality** (not strict);

This code:

```
$a = 0;
if ($a == 1) throw new Exception("Message");
echo "Dose not execute for $a == 0";
```

**works**. I.E., the `echo` works ("Dose not execute for 0 == 0"), since `$a != 1.` and no exception is thrown.
You should use single quotes to have a message (wrong as it is) like "Dose not execute for $a == 0", since with double quotes the variable is subsitute in the string.

this code:

```
$a = 1;
if ($a == 1) throw new Exception("Message");
echo "Dose not execute for $a == 0";
```

**throws an exception**, which stops the running of the script and the echo doesn't get executed. So, it works.

A code like yours,

```
$a == 0;
if ($a == 1) throw new Exception("Message");
echo "Dose not execute for $a == 0";
```

Simply **returns an Undefined variable error**, since $a is not defined. Most likely, you don't have error enabled/displayed and cannot, as a consequence, see anything.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with your version of PHP or another problem with Apache/Nginx.
Use the brackets to make sure what’s going on and make the code clearer.
And also use 3 equals because 1 and 0 can be confused with true or false

```
if ($a === 1) {
  echo "Does NOT execute for $a = 0";
  throw new Exception("Message");      
}
echo "Does execute for $a = 0";
```